# Create flat VMWare Image from a hard drive

Tags: vmware-workstation, hard-drive

I have a ubuntu installed on a partition on my hard drive and I have finally gotten ubuntu to work *just* the way I like it. However, using a partition of my hard drive as the main disk in my vmware machine is really slow.

I would like to just be able to make an **exact** copy of what is on this partition--but in a vmdk.

However, I would like to have some room to spare on the disk and I want it to be a flat image (30gb or so) for it to perform even faster.

I am using Workstation 7 in Windows 7.

Comment: Please humor my ignorant question .. why is running from a VM faster than running from a native partition?

Comment: I honestly don't know why, but in my experience it is much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a conversion wizard for that. You can find it at File->Import or Export in the main menu.

Comment: I will check that when I boot back into Windows.

Comment: i just re installed windows, don't worry I haven't forgotten you...I will get around to figuring this out.

Answer (score 1):

VMware converter sounds like what you're looking for:

http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/

Comment: I used the File->Export then I used the converter.